# Residuals in double seasonal exponential smoothing

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive, seasonality, exponential-smoothing

I have a time series with muliple seasonal cycles, which are 24 and 168 hours for my case. I would like to use Double Seasonal Exponential Smoothing method to forecast, which was published by James W. Taylor (http://users.ox.ac.uk/~mast0315/). The link for his article is [here](http://users.ox.ac.uk/~mast0315/ExpSmDoubleSeasonal.pdf)

When I check Taylor's paper and all other papers in the literature, I saw that AR(1) adjustment has been implemented to the residuals. Is it a coincidence to make AR(1) correction to residuals of all the time series, that have been used in these papers?

I am using "forecast" package in R by Rob Hyndman, http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf

Firstly, I run the code without using an AR(1) model for the errors.

```
    data <- scan("data.dat", skip=1)
    datatimeseries <- ts(data)
    library(forecast)
    dataforecasts <- dshw(datatimeseries, 24, 168, armethod=FALSE)
    res=dataforecasts$residuals
    acf(res)
    pacf(res)
```

Below, you can see the ACF and PACF graphs of the residuals.
[image]
[image]

As you can see there are some serious non-zera autocorrelation. I can not do AR(1) correction as papers suggest because PACF does not show it.I do not know what to do. I am sorry if it's a silly question however I am so new to time series. Would you please care to explain what to do next step-by-step and elaborately. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The AR(1) error would help a lot. But if you want something more general and flexible, use the `tbats` function instead.

Comment: Mr. Hyndman, When I do AR(1), no matter what the graphs depict, I still get non-zero autocorrelations. That means I did not get a perfect model. thus, how I use this tbats function you mentioned and why?

Comment: First, you may never get a perfect model. Second, I've already explained why -- it is more general and flexible. Third, if you want to know how to use a function, read the help file.